Can the Jenkins Perforce plugin handle syncing at a certain changelist?
I am trying this in a scripted pipeline
p4sync (
    charset: 'none', 
    credential: 'P4Credentials', 
    format: 'jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-${JOB_NAME}',
    populate: syncOnly(
        force: true, 
        have: true, 
        modtime: false, 
        parallel: [enable: true, minbytes: '1024', minfiles: '1', threads: '4'], 
        pin: '', 
        quiet: false,
        streamAtChange: "999999",
        revert: false), 
        source: depotSource("//ourDepot/develop/project/...")                           
)

It always just syncs to the latest revision and seems to ignore streamAtChange (which is what I thought would determine the synced CL).
I've tried moving streamAtChange alongside Source and in various other places to no avail.

pin is typically used for "sync at change", where the pin value is a typically a changelist ### or label, and gives a p4 sync //ourDepot/project/...@###.   streamAtChange applies to Stream clients and you're using a "depotSource()" as opposed to streamSource().

@JBrown You're a hero. Thank you so much that was exactly what I needed!
